# Why does a custom 'contained' highlight match interfere with the C syntax highlighting?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I am having an issue, which I was able to reduce to the following sequence of commands:

```
setf c
syntax region templatyExpression matchgroup=Special start='{{' end='}}'
syntax region templatyStatement matchgroup=Special start='{%' end='%}'
syntax match templatyIdentifier '\v[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' contained containedin=templatyStatement,templatyExpression
```

From the moment I type the last command, the following C code is improperly highlighted in a test file:

```
#define FOO 1
mdddddd ddd n
```

Where **m** stands for macro-coloured highlighting, **d** for default highlighting and **n** for the highlighting associated with numbers.

My question is: why is that? From what I have understood, `contained`, together with `containedin`, should only apply the highlighter when within something like `{{ foo }}` and leave everything else untouched. The rest of my highlighting code works as expected. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: For anyone who's interested, the full code can be found on https://github.com/samvv/vim-templaty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `contains=CONTAINED` you can define for regions. See `:h syn-contains`.

```
contains=CONTAINED
        If the first item in the contains list is "CONTAINED", then
        all groups will be accepted that have the "contained"
        argument.
```

So it means that no matter if you specified `contained containedin=GROUP` to be contained in `GROUP` it would also be contained in every other regions that have `contains=CONTAINED` or `contains=ALL`

Comment: Aah now I get it! Thank you so much for answering this! Will try it out now and see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much for helping out, I was gradually losing my mind on this one.